# Transaction handling in AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

I have implemented an AWS lambda function that talks to the RDS database. For a requirement, this lambda deletes a record from the database and moves forward to do other things in the code. For deleting a record, it uses Hibernate transaction. So far so good.

For an unhappy scenario, whenever an exception occurs after deleting a record from DB, lambda throws an exception. Now the problem is that lambda throws an exception after deleting a record. We lost the data here.

How can I roll back the transaction which is already committed from inside the Lambda function after a record has been deleted?

UPDATED Below

In my case, Lambda throwing NullPointerException and we are using try-catch block inside Lambda function, and error is getting logged appropriately from the Catch block.

Lambda calls the below method to delete the person object. Here we are using EntityManager to delete it using Hibernate which is interacting AWS Aurora RDS cluster.

```
public void deletePersonObject(Person person) {
    EntityManager entityManager = sessionFactory().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    try {
        transaction.begin();
        entityManager.remove(person);
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("error while inserting person details: {}", person.getId(), e);
        transaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Now the problem is that lambda throws an exception` what exception? Lambdas do not just suddenly terminate

Comment: It is NullPointerException in my case. But I want to roll back the delete transaction regardless of the exception Lambda throws. I've added some more details in the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rollback transaction in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26200324/how-to-rollback-transaction-in-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AWS's RDS Data Service? Because it looks like [there's a rollback operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rdsdataservice/latest/APIReference/API_RollbackTransaction.html):

> ```
> POST /RollbackTransaction HTTP/1.1
> Content-type: application/json
>
> {
>   "resourceArn": "string",
>   "secretArn": "string",
>   "transactionId": "string"
> }
> ```

You would need to implement logic to notice that your lambda threw an exception, decide that a rollback is necessary, and perform the rollback. This could be a `try-catch` in the lambda itself, or it could be a separate lambda, listening to the DLQ of the first.

Comment: Yes RDS but we are using Hibernate which is interacting with RDS. Using the API which you are suggesting, requires transactionID, I am not sure how I will retrieve it using JPA (added details in the main question). It looks like, I will have to create the transaction from API only not JPA.